# How to materialize 2 params from Source[ByteString, Any] akka streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream

So i can materialize inputStream and Feature[ByteString] from Source[ByteString, Any]

```
val bs = fileStream.runWith(Sink.head)
val is = fileStream.runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream())
```

how can i get it using one operation ?

Comment: `Any` is generally a symptom of something not good

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```scala
val bs: (Future[ByteString], InputStream) = Source.empty[ByteString]
    .alsoToMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(StreamConverters.asInputStream())(Keep.both)
    .run()
```